# Java: Recognizing keyPressed only once per press

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm making a game in Java where I want to be able to walk up to an NPC and press space to talk to them. However, my KeyBoard class right now is geared toward the movement keys (wasd & up down left right), where it's always recognizing the press to keep the player moving. How would I set it up so that the space bar would only be recognized once it's pressed and wouldn't be recognizable until the player released it and pressed it again?

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener
{

    private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];

    public boolean up, down, left, right, interact;

    public void update() 
    {
        up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
        interact = keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE];
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: create a `retrieveAndReset` method that gets the value, and if `true` sets it to `false`? Methods should be preferred to direct variable access anyway, you would not require the `update()` method. You may not want to reset the spacebar value when you release it; a short key press should be registered as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set<Integer> pressedKeys = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
  int code = ke.getKeyCode();
  Integer val = Integer.valueOf(code);
  if (pressedKeys.contains(val)) {
    //we've already pressed the key and it is being held down
    return;
  }
  else {
    //process key event
  }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyVEnt ke) {
  pressedKeys.remove(ke.getKeyCode());
}
```